# Eclipse Memory Analyzer does not show java processes

Tags: java, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Having some java applications, which are just compatible with JDK8, I set my environment variable %JAVA_HOME% to the JDK8 path. Furthermore I would like to analyze memory leaks using Eclipse Memory Analyszer Tool (MAT) within these applications.

So i have downloaded AdoptiumJDK17, installed it, but did *not* set JAVA_HOME for this JDK. For starting MAT I have used the `-vm` Parameter for setting JDK17 in the ini-file. MAT is starting fine, but `File` -> `Acquire Head Dump` does not show any java.exe running with JDK8 in the background.

Is there any possibility to find these processes?

Comment: what is your operation system?

Comment: Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same JDK version to run MAT than the process that you want to analyze. Also both should be executed by the same user to avoid permission issues.

Comment: That I think the problem. THese applications are not able to run with JRE9+. And MAT need at least JDK17 (based on the latest version of MAT). I used the same users - this should not be the problem.

Comment: You can download an older version of MAT that works with JDK 8. It will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Configure...' button on the 'Acquire Heap Dump Dialog' to set up the 'HPROF jmap dump provider' and configure 'jdkhome' to point to the JDK directory matching the target JDK 8 applications.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try as soon as possible; I will let you know ...